# Pageable object is ignored / not instantiated on a @RestController

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-restcontroller

On a SpringBoot application, There is a @RestController, that contains the following api:

```
@GetMapping("/api")
public SomeDto getMyApi(@RequestParam UUID userId, Pageable pageable) {
    return testService.getMyApi(pageable,userId);
}
```

When calling the api either from a Javascript client app, or from Swagger, the Pageable object is always instantiated with the default values (page:0, size:21).
Even when called with the following request generated by Swagger:

```
.../api?offset=0&pageNumber=3&pageSize=100&userId=2d02a66e-d7b1-49b3-9fe2-5ec4ff3abffc
```

This is how it looks like when debugging:
[image]

What is done wrong here?

Comment: `page` not `pageNumber` and `size` not `pageSize` in the query

Comment: @Toerktumlare Yes, If I put size, the "size" works, but not the "page". Why in swagger are the parameters with the names as I showed in the url?

Comment: please dont ask new questions in comments, but the short answer is swagger generates code in a specific way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Swagger is not generating the correct parameters for you. Check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.paging-and-sorting) documentation of Spring Data for correct parameter names. If you are using Springfox for Swagger, by the time of writing this answer parameter name problem is an [open issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2623).